# Phonegap 3.5 and Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: xcode, cordova

I use the latest version of Phonegap (3.4) and Xcode 5.1.1

I created a website with jQuery Mobile I would like to include in Xcode to test with Phonegap ...

I created a new project from the command line.

```
phonegap create myproject 
cd myproject 
run phonegap ios
```

My new project is consrtuit and I can access it in Xcode. 
The problem is that I can not add / delete a file in the www directory from Xcode ... 
If I change the default index.html file changes are not taken and i don't have errors ...

If i see my project in the emulator, the update are not taken.[image: Xcode can't delete file]

Do you know what I could miss?

Thank you.

Comment: once you make changes you need to run `phonegap prepare ios`. This will ensure everything is added correctly.

Comment: this command dosen't work : "prepare ios is not a phonegap command"

Comment: ok, try `phonegap build ios`

Comment: The command works but my problem remains the same ...

Comment: did you find an answer?

Comment: No answer, i have use the phonegap build instead... You have the same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your changes in the project's /www folder, then in the terminal (starting from the project folder), type cordova prepare ios (or phonegap prepare ios). In Xcode, do a Project > Clean to purge the old contents, then the files should be up to date.